# Dynamic table with Javascript with input, button and picture

Tags: javascript, image, html-table

I am trying to make a page that creates table rows that include a **text input box**, a **button** that loads an image and an image box. It also includes a start and stop to cycle through the images.

Now the code I have written works, besides the cycling function, and I am sure that the showpic can be simplified. What do you think?

```js
var count = -1

function addline() {
  var table = document.getElementById("a");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
  var temp = count;
  cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text'/>";
  cell2.innerHTML = "<button>Load</button>";
  cell2.setAttribute("onclick", "showpic(this)");
  count++;
  cell2.setAttribute("id", count);
}

function showpic(a) {
  var table = document.getElementById("a");
  var cell3 = table.rows[a.id].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
  cell3.innerHTML = "<img><img/>";
  var link = table.rows[a.id].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  cell3.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute("src", link);
}

function slides() {
  var i = 0;
  myvar = setInterval(function() {
    showpic(i);
    i++
  }, 1000);
}

function stopslides() {
  clearInterval(myvar);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Erg 11</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="addline()">Add</button>
  <button onclick="slides()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="stopslides()">Stop</button>
  <p>
    <table border="1" id="a">
    </table>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where you want to show pics while sliding?

Comment: I guess sliding is the wrong word, it just needs to activate them like load would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were passing the wrong value to `showpic` from `startSlides`. Try this

```js
var count = -1

function addline() {
  var table = document.getElementById("a");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
  var temp = count;
  cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text'/>";
  cell2.innerHTML = "<button>Load</button>";
  cell2.setAttribute("onclick", "showpic(this)");
  count++;
  cell2.setAttribute("id", count);
}

function showpic(element) {
  var table = document.getElementById("a");
  var cell3 = table.rows[element.id].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
  cell3.innerHTML = "<img><img/>";
  var link = table.rows[element.id].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  cell3.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute("src", link);
}

function slides() {
  var i = 0;
  var rows = document.getElementById("a").rows;
  myvar = setInterval(function() {
    showpic(rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]);
    i++;
    if (i > count) {
      stopslides();
    }

  }, 1000);
}

function stopslides() {
  clearInterval(myvar);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Erg 11</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="addline()">Add</button>
  <button onclick="slides()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="stopslides()">Stop</button>
  <p>
    <table border="1" id="a">
    </table>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!That was indeed the problem.